# expected struct `Vec3d`, found type parameter `u32` when implmenting the Mul trait for a custom struct

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement the `Mul` trait for the `Vec3d` struct. I want the `mul` function to multiply each element of `Vec3d` by a number and return a `Vec3d`. However I am getting faced with this error:

```
error[E0053]: method `mul` has an incompatible type for trait
  --> src\vec_3d.rs:26:21
   |
23 | impl<u32> Mul for Vec3d<u32> {
   |      --- this type parameter
...
26 |     fn mul(self, t: u32) -> Self::Output {
   |                     ^^^
   |                     |
   |                     expected struct `Vec3d`, found type parameter `u32`
   |                     help: change the parameter type to match the trait: `Vec3d<u32>`
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `fn(Vec3d<_>, Vec3d<u32>) -> Vec3d<_>`
              found fn pointer `fn(Vec3d<_>, u32) -> Vec3d<_>`
```

My code looks like this:

```
use std::ops::Add;
use std::ops::Mul;

#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct Vec3d<T> {
    pub x: T,
    pub y: T,
    pub z: T,
}
```

```
impl<u32> Mul for Vec3d<u32> {
    type Output = Self;

    fn mul(self, t: u32) -> Self::Output {
        Self {
            x: self.x * t,
            y: self.x * t,
            z: self.x * t,
        }
    }
}
```

I had this originally with the generic type parameter `T`:

```
impl<T: Mul<Output = T>> Mul for Vec3d<T> {
    type Output = Self;

    fn mul(self, t: T) -> Self::Output {
        Self {
            x: self.x * t,
            y: self.x * t,
            z: self.x * t,
        }
    }
}
```

I have seen this be done the same way in some examples and other questions. What is wrong and how I can implement this the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nearly the same as the example on the `Mul` documentation: [Multiplying vectors by scalars as in linear algebra](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Mul.html#multiplying-vectors-by-scalars-as-in-linear-algebra)

`Mul` has a default generic, which you can see in the trait definition:

```rs
pub trait Mul<Rhs = Self> {
```

This offers convenience since most implementers of `Mul` will be multiplying against `Self`. You aren't, so you need to specify the generic:

```rs
impl Mul<u32> for Vec3d<u32> {
    type Output = Self;

    fn mul(self, t: u32) -> Self::Output {
        Self {
            x: self.x * t,
            y: self.y * t,
            z: self.z * t,
        }
    }
}
```

To make this fully generic, you might try this:

```rs
impl<T: Mul<Output = T>> Mul<T> for Vec3d<T>
```

However, since you're using a single `T` 3 times, you would need to restrict it to `Clone` or `Copy`. The usual way to get around this is to implement `Mul` for references:

```rs
impl<'a, T> Mul<&'a T> for Vec3d<T>
where
    T: Mul<&'a T, Output = T>,
{
    type Output = Self;

    fn mul(self, t: &'a T) -> Self::Output {
        Self {
            x: self.x * t,
            y: self.y * t,
            z: self.z * t,
        }
    }
}
```

Then you probably want a non-reference version for when the type implements `Copy`:

```rs
impl<T> Mul<T> for Vec3d<T>
where
    T: Mul<Output = T> + Copy,
{
    type Output = Self;

    fn mul(self, t: T) -> Self::Output {
        Self {
            x: self.x * t,
            y: self.y * t,
            z: self.z * t,
        }
    }
}
```

But even better, you can do both of those in one impl:

```rs
impl<T, R> Mul<R> for Vec3d<T>
where
    R: Copy,
    T: Mul<R, Output = T>,
{
    type Output = Self;

    fn mul(self, t: R) -> Self::Output {
        Self {
            x: self.x * t,
            y: self.y * t,
            z: self.z * t,
        }
    }
}
```

When `R` is `&T` you cover the first impl, and when `R` is `T` and `Copy` you cover the second impl. `&` references are always `Copy`.

Another common thing to do is implement `Mul` for every integer type, which allows you more control over the implementation, for example if you wanted to optimize them for certain sized integers.